# The OutputPath property is not set for project ... / VS arbirtrarily changing configuration of projects in solution from Debug to Release

Tags: visual-studio, build, nuget

Last last week I started having an issue with every solution I've tried to build with Visual Studio. I was using VS 2019 and our organization had just pushed down some windows updates (not sure if that's related) but after the updates I was on VS 2019 version 16.8.4, .Net version 4.8.03752.

Whenever I try to build one of our solutions (I tried 3 different solutions after doing a free pull from the main branch of our repo) I get over 1000 errors which seem to be cascade errors from the OutputPath property not being set which seems to be related to several of the projects being arbitrarily changed from Debug to Release even though the solution is set to Debug | Any CPU.

Furthermore, if I examine the build tab on the project properties (or examine them in configuration manager) NO DEBUG CONFIGURATION IS SHOWN AS AVAILABLE. If I close Visual Studio it prompts to me save changes and if I do a comparison shows that it did indeed change the configuration of several projects form Debug to Release.

I have reproduced this on 2 separate machines, with fresh installs of Visual Studio 2019 (and 2017) and pulling fresh code from the repos. Other developers in my org an build the solutions just fine and their configurations show Debug | Any CPU across the board (i.e. I seem to be the only person in the world having this problem and I'm having it on every machine I've tried and with multiple versions of Visual Studio).

I also see errors saying that projects contains nuget references that are "missing" but if I restore nuget pacakges I get a messages saying they are all installed and there is nothing to restore. I also see the "missing" packages in the packages folder.

We use relative paths for the packages so it can't be the typical literal-path issue some people have. Besides which, my folder structure hasn't changed and we all use the same folder structure in our ord.

I am completely at a loss as to what to try next. My googlefoo has completely failed me in this regard.

I'm desperately hoping someone in the Stack Exchange world can offer a solution.

Thanks,

Greg.

Comment: Hi Greg, if you have a workaround, you could add an answer about it to share it with us. And it could help other community members search and handle similar issues. And it is kind of you to do that:)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your project's `csproj` file has missed these content:

You could directly add these at the bottom of the `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**After that**, delete `bin` and `obj` folder.

**Then**, run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**--> **Package Manager Console** to reinstall all nuget packages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked and those sections are already present in the .csproj files. But when I open configuration manager it shows Release | Any CPU and the dropdown only shows Release, <New>, <Edit>. 

If I close and exit Visual Studio it prompts me to save the solution. If I save and do a diff I see that it changed the entries for those projects from Debug to Release.

Comment: Here's a link to a short video demonstrating the problem. 
https://youtu.be/dFoI_q90x0k